# How do I put list of figures and list of tables on separate pages?

Tags: table-of-contents, page-breaking, tocloft

When I put `\usepackage{tocloft}` in the preamble the pages that had list of figures and list of tables have been shifted forward. List of figures now starts on the contents page and list of tables starts on the list of figures page.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

With `tocloft`, the ToC, the LoT and the LoF don't 
start new pages when using document classes in which without the package they normally would do. If you want the lists to start a new page, you have two options:

1. Manually issue a `\cleardoblepage` command. For example:

   ```
   \documentclass{book}
   \usepackage[titles]{tocloft}

   \begin{document}

   \tableofcontents
   \cleardoublepage
   \listoffigures
   \cleardoublepage
   \listoftables
   \cleardoublepage

   \end{document}
   ```
2. Use the `titles` package option:

   ```
   \documentclass{book}
   \usepackage{tocloft}

   \begin{document}

   \tableofcontents
   \listoffigures
   \listoftables

   \end{document}
   ```

The difference between both approaches is that the second one will make the titles of the LoF, LoT and LoF to follow any possible modification made to the formatting of the sectional unit producing the titles.

Comment: This is another peculiarity of the `tocloft` package that should be controlled by a package option.

Comment: Actually, `\cleardoublepage` is the appropriate command -- it will force ListsofXXX to the next *odd* page if the `openright` class option is in effect (as by default in the `book` class).

Comment: @egreg: There is an option `titles`.

Comment: @lockstep you're right. I've edited my answer. Thank you.

Comment: @MarcoDaniel I've incorporated this option to my answer, with a little note on the effect of the `titles` option. Thank you.

Comment: @GonzaloMedina: I actually used \clearpage instead of \cleardoublepage and the problem was solved. Wasn't \clearpage your first suggestion?